# Is it allowed to declare a nested class object outside the scope?

Tags: c++, c++11, inner-classes, private-members, decltype

```
#include <type_traits>

auto f()
{
    struct A { int f() { return 0; } };

    return A();
}

int main()
{
    std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(f())> a;

    return a.f();
}
```

The code above can be compiled successfully. I just wonder:

**Is it legal as per the C++ standard?**

Comment: Yes, it's allowed.

Comment: This kind of types that can be used but not named outside of their own scope are commonly nicknamed "Voldemort types" :)

Comment: const auto& f()
 {
    struct A { int f() { return 0; }};

  return A();
 }
you are returning ref to local

Comment: @Quentin why is that? Or is it just pointing out that it's unnecessarily confusing (as the fact this question exists seem to imply)?

Comment: @Oppen It's a reference to Harry Potter, where Voldemort is also known in-universe as He-Who-Must-Not-Be-Named. The types are nowhere near as scary as the guy though!

Comment: I know who Voldemort is, but didn't make the connection with the nickname.